# Android Dynamic Array

Tags: android, arrays, dynamic-arrays, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML file through Android Pull Parser technique. First, have a look at the below XML file:

```
<childs>
    <students>
        <name> hello </name>
        <address> xyz </address>
    </stdents>      

    <students>
        <name> abc </name>
        <address> def </address>
    </stdents>      

</childs>
```

Consider that I'm parsing the above file. Now, my problem is that I want to create a separate array for name and address. So while parsing, I want to store 1st student's data in `name[0]` and `address[0]` and the next student's data in `name[1]` and `address[1]`. In short, **array size is extending as more data is parsed.**

**Is there any way to do so? I mean to create a dynamic extendable array?** Or if there is another way to do so then please help me to fight with this problem.

Comment: @Marcin Gil but i exacly want as separated array becoz want to display the array data in "ListAdapter"

Comment: Why not use ArrayAdapter<T> that can take List as argument? If you plan to use ListView that would be no problem.

Comment: @Marcin Gil but i have implemented with "BaseAdapter" becoz i am making customization to the listview as image with 2 textviews

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Vector<String>` and then (if you need an array) copy the data to array(s) using `toArray` method.

```
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        v.add(new String(Integer.toString(i)));

    Object s[] = v.toArray();

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        str = s[i].toString();
```

Another option:

```
    String a[] = {};
    v.toArray(a);
```

Comment: @Asahi thanx a lot...now let me try it out in my problem way

Comment: However you should probably use ArrayList instead of Vector as Vector is syncronized.

Comment: @Asahi Thanx a lot...You saved my life finally i have implemented Vector and then converted it into Array

Comment: But however...if any better and appropriate solution also welcomed

Comment: ArrayList is also an  option - depending on your requirements to synchronization

Comment: hey who has down-voted to this answer...it really helps me a lot

Comment: To use Vector in 2010? Bleee. It is synchronized by default.

Answer (score 2):

You use and List array like this

```
List<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> address=new ArrayList<String>(); 
name.add(StudyParser.getValue(eimg, "name"));  
address.add(StudyParser.getValue(eimg,"address")
```

where StudyParser.getValue(); is method which u call to get data

Answer (score 0):

The most simple method to create an unlimited size array is using String Builder.
This allow you to add many elements in runtime.
It has 3 major components.

1. Decleration and Initialization.
2. Value addition/ Append
3. Print out/ Usage

Use the bellow code anywhere in Android Studio.

```js
//Basic Decleration
        StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
        
//Adding data
       myString.append("Hello text <br>");
        myString.append("some more data <br>");
        myString.append("more data to store <br>");
        
//Displaying in already created text view
        deviceDetails.setText(Html.fromHtml(callLogs+""));
```

Note: I'm treating this as HTML string and "
" tags will create the next line in text view. So, all added data will be displayed in a new line.